# Can I reinstall windows without loosing my dualboot?

Tags: windows, dual-boot

I installed windows 10 in 50% of my SSD Then, i installed linux in other 50% (OS Only)

And i have 75% HDD for Linux + 15% for windows (Data only)

Everything worked fine until Windows update broke windows: blue screen at boot, "inaccessible boot device".. A classic problem in dualboot with windows.

Now, I would like to reinstall w10 in it's partition. I don't want to break my linux installation, so i prefer asking here:

Can I clic "Next" here ?

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers-sm/2018/32/3/1533749163-153374898848492883863.jpg

The partition selected is the windows partition is my SSD. I hope it will not recreate shemas of disk, destroy other partitions, or something else

Thanks !

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is not a Unix oriented question.

Comment: Forum is Unix & linux, right ? https://i.imgur.com/1thbWOp_d.jpg?maxwidth=640&shape=thumb&fidelity=medium

Answer (score 1):

Can't speak for W10, but MS wants to break your Linux installation any way it can. Here's how I've done it with XP.

Back up data you need from the linux partitions with a live disk just in case. Boot Gparted-Live to look around and perhaps reformat the Win NTFS system partition (probably sda1). Do not muck about with any other partitions!

Then reinstall Win to that partition (somehow). Now with the install media for the exact Linux distro you'd used, perform a GRUB repair sequence. You may need to edit /etc/fstab (and reboot) after the GRUB repair so the Linux side understands your disk layout.

If you're lucky, you'll have everything back and usable,

Answer (score 0):

A backup is always a good idea, not only in this situation.

Windows will overwrite you boot sector (MBR), but you can create a copy of the MBR and restore it later. You need a way to boot into Linux, like a life CD, to restore the MBR. Also you should not change partition sizes when installing Windows.